# Trying to Get A Line Count for all Files in a Directory and Sub-Directories using a Bat File

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo

I am trying to get this bat file i am working on to provide me with a list of documents in a directory (and all of the sub-directories) and the line counts per document.

I have been able to get the code below to work but it only provides me the documents in the root of the folder, none of the sub-directories. I've searched so many different forums but have been unable to find a workable answer.

```
@echo off

:start
cls
echo Enter full path to directory that you want to count files for:
set /P FilePath=
echo ..
echo ...
if exist %FilePath%\CountLines.csv del %FilePath%\CountLines.csv /q
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`find /v /c "" "%FilePath%"\*.*`) do echo %%a >> "%FilePath%"\CountLines.csv
pause()
goto start
```

This is the output i get, which is correct but its not returning docs in the sub-directories

```
MD5HASH APPEARS ONCE.csv 1174690 
Split.txt 4258 
COUNTLINESINFILES.txt 1
```

Comment: All documents cannot be processed using that method and the code you have posted most certainly cannot output the information you've told us it has.

Comment: Open up a `cmd.exe`window, enter `for /?` at the prompt and read up on how the command you've provided works.

Comment: I see that you've edited your output but it still doesn't match the output possible from the included code snippet. If you cannot adequately explain your issue and do not use [mcve] code  and it's respective output, you will not receive suitable answers.

Comment: Apologies, i updated the code above to the full command i am using. I omitted the FilePath in the find command earlier. But this does run in a bat and provides the output i showed.

Comment: So why can you not just put your main code under a label and run a loop over all of your files calling the label with the output from the loop as an agument to set to `%FilePath%`, or replace it!

Comment: I am really new to batch scripting so i am picking these up on the fly or through forums and then manipulating them to my needs. Let me see if i can figure out what your suggestion. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo Enter full path to directory that you want to count files for:

rem Get path of the directory to search.
set /P "FilePath=" || (
    >&2 echo Invalid reply.
    exit /b 1
)

rem Check if the dir path exists.
if not exist "%FilePath%\" (
    >&2 echo Invalid path.
    exit /b 1
)

echo ..
echo ...

rem Get count of lines of files in the dir path.
(
    for /r "%FilePath%" %%A in (*) do (
        find /v /c "" "%%~A"
    )
) > "%FilePath%\CountLines.csv"

echo Results:
type "%FilePath%\CountLines.csv"
pause
```

If setting variables in a script, `setlocal` can help to
keep the variables local to the script.
`setlocal` has been added.

Consider that if the user presses <kbd>return</kbd>, without
entering anything, then that can be a invalid path else a
path starting with a single backslash can be interpreted
as from the root of a drive. I do not consider the user may
consider that so the `||` is a failure check, and executes
the parenthesed code if it is a failure.

Check if the replied path is valid before continuing.

The `for /r` loop will iterate recursively with the
pattern of `*`. `find` will read each file and the
stdout is written to file. With the whole `for /r`
within parentheses, allows all stdout to be written
to file before closing the file handle.

The results are shown at the end by using `type`.

See `for /?` for help with understanding `for /r`
and all the other types of `for` loops.

Comment: This works perfectly and the explanation really helps me understand what is going with the script and how i would need to configure any updates or use some of it in different function. Thank you very much.